# How do I get the size of a request in postman

Tags: postman

I have a post request with multipart/form-data type in postman. I want to know the size of the entire request body before or even after the request is sent. I have tried using the console and pre-request scripts but none are showing me this information. The content-length header shown for the request is `<calculated when request is sent>`. Running `console.log(pm.request.size())` in pre-request scripts shows

```
{
 body: 0
 header: 104
 total: 104
 source: "COMPUTED"
}
```

which is not what I want. The body I am posting has several file and text entries, and the size cannot be 0.
My postman version is 10.18.1.

Comment: How did you try using console and pre-request script? Please add that to the question